# Checkout not functioning in osCommerce

Tags: checkout, oscommerce

I have a problem with the checkout

`step 2 "Payment Information",`

I have 2 payment modules installed `google checkout` and `paypal`,

the problem is that i cant go the the `step 3` dont know why, when I press continue button then nothing happends. Below is the link provided.

Is there any reason, why this problem persist.. and what will its solution.

[www.yuppieisland.com](http://www.yuppieisland.com)

Comment: even i stuck out here .. seems.. did you remove the ssl from that page

Comment: Have you noticed that your checkout link redirects to different domain - yuppieisland.netfirms.com/yuppieisland.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's a problem on "checkout_confirmation.php"

maybe your layout break some restrictions showing the payment methods, in my checkout_confirmation.php there's only 1 redirection to checkout_payment.php:

```
if ( ( is_array($payment_modules->modules) && (sizeof($payment_modules->modules) > 1) && !is_object($$payment) ) || (is_object($$payment) && ($$payment->enabled == false)) ) {
```

Your checkout_confirmation.php can be different (it may depend of addons) check the redirects of your checkout_confirmation.php to checkout_payment.php to see when it redirects to that page to check errors.